# Ubiquity process root certificate not valid

Tags: macos, keychain

What are com.apple.ubiquity.... certificates in keychain? I have three of them and the Keychain access warns me that their root certificates are invalid. I previously had little snitch asking me about Ubiquity(ubd process) wanting to connect to configuration.apple.com. Anybody has any ideas about it? There are also other processes like AWACS that try to connect to Apple servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificates are probably self signed certificates that get generated to make each mac unique and avoid sending data in the clear between macs and macs/apple servers performing iCloud services.

[image]

As for the processes you mentioned, these belong to iCloud and back to my mac location services and are part of a normal installation of Lion. You'd need to checksum / verify binaries to be sure you are safe, but the presence of them shouldn't be startling as they are normal processes on Macs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do i verify them as they have been bundled with the Lion OS?

Comment: the typical manner is to perform a clean install and checksum or catalog the files installed. You can get lists by examining the receipts files and using tools like lsbom - http://www.macworld.com/article/1047341/viewprogdetails.html